# Is there a built-in function wrapper to map *args to args?

Tags: python-3.x, standard-library

Python implementation:

```
def function_name(f):
    return lambda *args:f(args)
```

Usage:

```
>>> arg_sum = function_name(sum)
>>> arg_sum(1, 2, 4, 8)
15
```

Is there a way to do this using the standard library? I would expect it to be in `functools` but I couldn't find it (as of Python 3.6).

Comment: Also, what would this function be called? I don't know what to look for.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this existed in the stdlib. It's rarely useful and easy to implement if you really need it.

Comment: @Aran-Fey That could be said for most of `functools` (apart from the "rarely useful" part, which only applies to ~25%).